# ActiveModel's `as_json` doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I want to customize json output of my ActiveModel instance with `as_json` method. But though  pass whitelist of attributes in `only` option, the result includes all attributes.

Here is example:

```
class Foo
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :a, :b
end  

Foo.new(a: 1, b: 2).as_json
# {"a" => 1, "b" => 2}

Foo.new(a: 1, b: 2).as_json(only: [:a])
# {"a" => 1, "b" => 2}
# but I expect {"a" => 1}
```

Is it I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot include `ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON` module and `attributes` method. After this fix all work as expected:

```
class Foo
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
  attr_accessor :a, :b

  def attributes
    {'a' => nil, 'b' => nil}
  end  
end  

Foo.new(a: 1, b: 2).as_json
# {"a" => 1, "b" => 2}

Foo.new(a: 1, b: 2).as_json(only: [:a])
# {"a" => 1}
```